# How to position Drawable over TextView in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-databinding

I'm trying to create strike-through text in my XML. I made a drawable (just a line), and draw it behind the text if a condition is met (using data binding). The problem is that my text and strikethrough are different colors, and when the drawable is added, it is drawn behind the text, which looks weird. I need it to appear over the text, not behind it. Currently, I have it using the `background` Android attribute, so it makes sense why it would be rendering behind the text, however I couldn't find any other options. The only related help I found online was to use `drawableTop`, but then the drawable wouldn't appear at all. Also, I can't do this programmatically, I want to do it in the xml so that I don't need to reference my views elsewhere. Any help would be appreciated. Here is some of my code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_xs"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_xs"
    android:text="@{@string/text(viewModel.insertThisIntoString)}"
    android:background="@{viewModel.displayStrikeThrough.value ? @drawable/strikethrough_text : null}"/>
```

and my drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/app_grey_300"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Code I used when trying to display ImageView over TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_xs"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_xs"
        android:text="@{@string/text(viewModel.insertThisIntoString)}"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/strikethrough_text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Ideally, I would want the layout_width of the ImageView to span the width of the TextView it's covering. What I tried was setting the width of the RelativeLayout to `wrap_content` (so that its width would match the width of the TextView), and set the width of the ImageView to `match_parent`, so that it would fill up the width of the RelativeLayout, and therefore the TextView, however that didn't work - the width would span the entire screen. I currently have it at 40dp to make sure it would appear.

Also, it should be noted that I tried setting the drawable as both the background and the src of the ImageView, neither of which worked.

Comment: put an imsgeview over the TextView

Comment: @VladMatvienko could you please provide an example of what that would look like? I've tried doing that as well (forgot to mention that in my post), but I couldn't get it to work. For some reason my drawable wouldn't render in that case either. I used RelativeLayout and put the ImageView after the TextView so that it would be above it in the heirarchy

Comment: I think you need to show the code of what you've tried. I suspect you didn't make ImageView to take same size as TextView

Comment: I added the code I used to try it out

Comment: asI expected: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` this means that image should take as high as it deeds, but in your case it need 0px since it is not an image in fact. Try setting some exact size to it, or make it match size of TextView

Comment: oh wow I can't believe I missed that, for some reason I figured I was already setting the thickness of the stroke and that would automatically scale to the height of it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll make it an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the `ImageView`, it will take as much height as it needs. But your `Drawable` is not a bitmap, and also has no size itself. So it will take exactly 0px height, as it needs 0px while not having size.
You should set some concrete value to the height, or make your `ImageView` match size of `TextView` depending on how you want it to look like.